# Add a class to table depending on slider value

Tags: jquery, css

I have a working script that adds padding to table cells based on the value of a user-configurable slider. The slider value goes from 15 to 30.

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("padding-slider");
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
 output.innerHTML = this.value;
      var items = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
 for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
   items[i].style.padding =  this.value + "px 0";
 }
}
```

I additionally want to add classes to the `table` based on the slider value:

18  =  `.font-med`

24  =  `.font-lrg`

30  =  `.font-x-lrg`

[codepen](https://codepen.io/stevland/pen/rNxQLYb)  [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/stevland/j27vh4w1/2/)

Comment: Use the `.addClass` functionality in this case. `$( "p" ).addClass( "myClass yourClass" );` https://api.jquery.com/addClass/. Don't forget to `.removeClass` when inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
var slider = document.getElementById("myRange");
var output = document.getElementById("padding-slider");
var thisTable = document.querySelector('table');
output.innerHTML = slider.value;

slider.oninput = function() {
 output.innerHTML = this.value;
  var thisVal = parseInt(this.value);
  if(thisVal === 18) {
    thisTable.setAttribute('class', 'queue font-med');
  } else if (thisVal === 24) {
    thisTable.setAttribute('class', 'queue font-lrg');
  } else if (thisVal === 30) {
    thisTable.setAttribute('class', 'queue font-x-lrg');
  } else {
    thisTable.setAttribute('class', 'queue');
  }
      var items = document.getElementsByClassName("cell");
 for (var i=0; i < items.length; i++) {
   items[i].style.padding =  thisVal + "px 0";
 }
}
```

Working Url : https://codepen.io/vinodmurukesan/pen/MWKzjQa

Comment: Nice effort - an answer should not be code only. Please consider adding some information on how you have achieved these results.

Comment: @Vinod  Hey, well done! It's a bit jerky, but that is my fault. You gave me exactly what I asked for, but what I should have stated was `18 - 24 = .font-med`, `24 - 29 = .font-lrg`, `30 = .font-x-lrg`.

Comment: @Vinod, I modified it like this `if (thisVal > 17 && thisVal < 24)` and it works perfectly. Thank you for your help!